# Alternatives to Google Analytics when needing to read and query often by many end users

Tags: google-analytics

We currently use Google Analytics to track things like user profile views, product views, shares etc. This was fine for our admins to see the data, but what we wanted to do was also display that data and aggregates of that within an iOS app, e.g. a little eye icon on a product with the total views it had. More complicated things too.

Google Analytics turned out not to be great for this - we hit rate limits by having thousands of users hit it to READ data, and needed to separate users by many buckets under a complicated mapping. In other words I think we were abusing google analytics by using it as somewhere we could store and real-time query stats to feed back into our app rather than just someplace admins could go and look at pretty graphs. The read functionality of GA seems more intended for the occasional user query, maybe if you wanted to feed into your own analytics panel or some such accessed by a small number of people.

Without building in-house analytics, are there any other 3rd party providers that would serve this purpose? In other words more a store of analytics data that could be both written to and queried often by many users in real-time, plus somewhere admins could go and see that data.

Comment: What about exporting to bigquery? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en

Comment: @PatrickMagee sounds quite promising, thanks